# Joining the same table twice and order by the same column

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables (events & organisations) in my database. Events has 4 columns: id, organiser, coorganiser and date.

Organisations has 3 columns: id, name, organisation_code.

organisation_code is a unique key, and organiser and coorganiser in the events table references this unique code.

I want to SELECT all organisations that appears in the organiser column and the coorganiser column within a daterange of events. Each organiser should only be listed once, no mater weather they appear as organiser og coorganiser, and ordered by name. and organiser can easily be coorganiser on one event, and organiser on another event. I still only want them listed once.

What i have come up joins the same table twice on two different columns. But that requires me to use Aliases, and the aliases stops me from being able to order by name for both joins, and grouping by organisation_code. My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT date, t1.code, t1.name, t2.code, t2.name FROM $events_table 
JOIN $organisations_table AS t1
    ON $events_table.organiser = t1.organisation_code
JOIN $organisations_table AS t2
    ON $events_table.coorganiser = t2.organisation_code

WHERE date > '2015-06-05' AND date < '2015-06-29'
GROUP BY t1.organisation_code
ORDER BY t1.name
```

Comment: Perhaps use only one join with this condition: `ON t1.organisation_code IN ( $events_table.organiser, $events_table.coorganiser )`

Comment: @kordirko Why a comment and not an answer? This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` (as expressed in the comments).  However, with this sort of problem, two `LEFT JOIN`s often perform better:

```
SELECT e.date, COALESCE(t1.code, t2.code) as code,
       COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) as name 
FROM $events_table e LEFT JOIN
     $organisations_table t1
     ON e.organiser = t1.organisation_code LEFT JOIN
     $organisations_table t2
     ON e.coorganiser = t2.organisation_code
WHERE e.date > '2015-06-05' AND e.date < '2015-06-29'
ORDER BY name
```

If the organizations only appear once, I don't see why the `group by` is necessary.